# Why doesn't the the cross-validation results summary in GridSearch (.cv_results_) mask irrelevant parameters as expected?

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv, svc, masked-array

I am fitting an `SVC` using sklearn with `GridSearchCV` over a set of parameters and expect some entries from the grid's cv_results_ returned attribute to be masked when parameters do not apply to that particular grid run (e.g. when the kernel is `linear`, I expect the `gamma` entry to be masked). Instead, all entries are populated, regardless of relevance, with no 'mask' applied as shown in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV)

Running the documented examples on sklearn version 1.2.1 and 1.3.1:

```
>>> from sklearn import svm, datasets
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf') , 'C':[1, 10], 'gamma': [0.1, 1]}
>>> svc = svm.SVC()
>>> clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters)
>>> clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

... my clf.cv_results_ shows all 2^3 = 8 combinations, with all masks of the masked_array as False. Copying the relevant entries from clf.cv_results_:

```
{'mean_fit_time': array([0.00106173, 0.00110359, 0.00094199, 0.00119796, 0.00092278, 0.00104046, 0.00092359, 0.00126338]),
 'std_fit_time': array([2.33411589e-04, 1.05827065e-04, 1.01234561e-04, 4.21319023e-05, 6.95271419e-05, 1.32059704e-04, 1.18666692e-04, 2.69801231e-04]),
 'param_C': masked_array(data=[1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10],
              mask=[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
        fill_value='?',
             dtype=object),
 'param_gamma': masked_array(data=[0.1, 0.1, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1],
              mask=[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
        fill_value='?',
             dtype=object),
 'param_kernel': masked_array(data=['linear', 'rbf', 'linear', 'rbf', 'linear', 'rbf',
                    'linear', 'rbf'],
              mask=[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
        fill_value='?',
             dtype=object),
 'params': [{'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.1, 'kernel': 'linear'},
  {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.1, 'kernel': 'rbf'},
  {'C': 1, 'gamma': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'},
  {'C': 1, 'gamma': 1, 'kernel': 'rbf'},
  {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.1, 'kernel': 'linear'},
  {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.1, 'kernel': 'rbf'},
  {'C': 10, 'gamma': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'},
  {'C': 10, 'gamma': 1, 'kernel': 'rbf'}]
}
```

To my understanding, every other mask for `param_gamma` should be `True` (whenever the kernel is linear).

I know irrelevant parameters are ignored, but their presence in the grid triggers separate runs of model training, judging by the separate entries into .cv_results_ and their respective slightly different training times in cross-validation. As this is unnecessarily computationally taxing. How do I avoid this behaviour?